# Is there some kind of certification for Apple developers?

Tags: ios, macos

I'm looking for a certification as an "Apple developer" but I don't know if that exists.

I found http://training.apple.com/certification but it only offers certification for OSX and Apple software like FinalCut.

Comment: I think if you have made 3 or more great "apps" (maybe you have already, of course), it is a good or way better as any cert some 3rd party would offer.  I can understand certs to supplement job experience like teaching or Firewalls, but devs can show a portfolio basically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no official certification. There are, though, **non-Apple-official** courses which are highly reputed, such as [Big Nerd Ranch's](http://www.bignerdranch.com/training), for instance.

Comment: +1 if you have a BNR course, you're usually good to go.

Answer (score 5):

Apple now [offer training](http://training.apple.com/) with software engineering focused courses for Swift and iOS:

> ## [App Development with Swift](https://training.apple.com/us/en/courses#tabnav-6)
>
> Swift is a powerful and intuitive programming language for macOS, iOS, watchOS, and tvOS. Writing Swift code is interactive and fun, the syntax is concise yet expressive, and Swift includes modern features developers love. Swift code is safe by design, yet also produces software that runs lightning fast.

With regard to [Apple certification](https://training.apple.com/us/en/recognition), they **do not** offer software engineering specific certification.

Comment: There do not appear to be any developer certifications from Apple, only exams for IT and Creative professionals.

Comment: Well the link above express then for mac professionals.

Comment: The page does not exist.

Comment: Seems there removed it. U can look into the updated link.

Answer (score 0):

only https://certiport.pearsonvue.com/Certifications/Apple/App-Dev-With-Swift/Overview has an official partnership with Apple to certify students on their Swift Programming knowledge and skills.

Their year-long Swift certification program covers high school and college-level knowledge of the programming language, which when attained can be a golden stamp on your iOS developer resume that can lead you to your dream iOS developer role!

I don’t think it’s absolutely necessary but if you’re all about the certifications, then there you go!